# MVC with Bootstrap - Edit vs View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have self taught myself MVC and create little personal projects to learn, as my IT consultancy always puts me into roles where I don't get to use MVC.

One thing I am battling with is - When I display a view, I always display it in edit mode. So you can make changes and clicks Save, and the view is saved. However, I would prefer to enter the view in Read Only mode. So, instead of edit boxes, I want labels (read-only). When the user clicks an Edit button, without a post back (so, using the same screen), editable fields 'change' into edit boxes.

I'd prefer to have one view though. Not en edit view and a view view. To minimize coding effort.

This must be a pretty standard function. Can it be done using Bootstrap/MVC?

Comment: You can use `readonly` for input fields and toggle it with javascript.

Comment: That may be an option. I was hoping, though, to display items as labels when initially opened, and then switch to edit boxes when going into edit view, as opposed to read only edit boxes initially. I render the boxes with Html.TextBoxFor ... so not sure this is too possible.

Comment: Then you will need to render both 'labels' and associated form controls and toggle them with javascript/jquery (but often done by displaying the form as a dialog)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - Is that a common approach to this sort of requirement? As I haven't worked on any commercial MVC applications, I'd like to learn best-practice. Is this a suitable solution? (Rendering both controls).

Comment: Personally I always have separate 'Details' and 'Edit' views, but its not uncommon to have an Edit button which displays a popup for editing the data (the form is either initially rendered in a hidden element, or by using ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial view of the form). Unless you expect that the view will be edited most times its viewed, then the 2nd approach would be better (no point initially rendering extra html if it wont be used)